# Converting url to imageView using Picasso

Tags: java, android, json, xml, picasso

I am using Picasso to convert url to imageView but getting an error. This is demo url i want to fetch url from json later on but demo url is even not working. Please check if any one can solve.

WordActivity.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Word>> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordActivity.class.getName();
    /**
     * URL for word data from the USGS dataset
     */
    private static String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harrypotter";
    /**
     * Adapter for the list of earthquakes
     */
    public WordAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView wordListView;
    ArrayList<Word> words;
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;
    private String mQuery = "";
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
        wordListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new WordAdapter(WordActivity.this, words);


        // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as input


        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface

        wordListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected word.


        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface

        // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the word data
        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        wordListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JGQBcu5O_ZcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api")
                .resize(200,200)
                .into(imageView);
        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (USGS_REQUEST_URL == null || networkInfo == null) {
            wordListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
            mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        }
        // If there is a network connection, fetch data

        final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_go_btn);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (USGS_REQUEST_URL == null || networkInfo == null) {
                    wordListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
                    mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
                }
                USGS_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Get the text from the EditText and update the mQuery value.
                mQuery = mEditText.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "+");
                // If it's empty don't proceed.
                if (mQuery.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(WordActivity.this, "Nothing to search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // Update the mRequestUrl value with the new mQuery.
                USGS_REQUEST_URL = USGS_REQUEST_URL + mQuery + "&maxResults=15";
                Log.i("onQueryTextSubmit", "mRequestUrl value is: " + USGS_REQUEST_URL);
                // Restart the loader.
                LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.restartLoader(1, null, WordActivity.this);
                Log.i("onClick", "loader restarted");
                View progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Try to make the progress bar appear again (not working)
                //View progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Update mRequestUrl back to its original value.
                USGS_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
                // This is what makes the ListView update with new info.

            }
        });
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //Update empty state with no connection error message
            wordListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
            mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Connection");
        }


    }

    public Loader<List<Word>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new WordLoader(this, USGS_REQUEST_URL);
    }

    /**
     * {@link } to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
     * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
     * <p>
     * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
     * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an EarthquakeAdapter. We won't do
     * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.
     * <p>
     * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
     * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
     * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
     * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
     * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
     */

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> earthquakes) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous word data
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        words.clear();
        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.

        if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {
            words.addAll(earthquakes);
        } else {
            wordListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Connection");
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      /*  words.addAll(earthquakes);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Word>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        words.clear();
    }


}
```

Error Msg

```
05-15 17:46:35.512 21319-21319/com.example.anandparmeetsingh.booklisting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.anandparmeetsingh.booklisting, PID: 21319
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anandparmeetsingh.booklisting/com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books.WordActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:553)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:536)
at com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books.WordActivity.onCreate(WordActivity.java:75)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

activity_word.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books.Book">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="32sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/magnitude"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_offset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/location_offset"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/primary_location"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="Mature"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your `activity_word.xml`

Comment: i check your url in picasso and it's working. Picasso is not your problem.[![This is snapshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faze7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faze7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function get bitmap

```
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't get this. Image is not visible but the app is not crashing. How do i get image in my imageView?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap=getBitmapfromUrl(imageurl);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @Parmeetsinghanand please check above my comment how to call function and setimage bitmap.

Comment: Can you help me using Picasso?@RatilalChopda

Answer (score 0):

imageView you're loading the image into is null. Check the resource id  R.id.imageView is correct.

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint after this line
   imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
the variable is non null?

Answer (score 0):

[image]your link is working Perfectly Fine.. I'm using Glide try this.! Read  [Glide Documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'

Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .override(200, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageView);

String url="http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg"
```

ProgressBar circular_progress;
   circular_progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularprogress);

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageview);


    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JGQBcu5O_ZcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api")
    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
       circular_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
        circular_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It's the same not helping.

Comment: So you solution is to remove the call to *resize* (the rest of the function call is exactly the same as in the question) ? Interesting... Can you explain why *resize* causes an IllegalArgumentException ?

Comment: @Parmeetsinghanand do not pay attention to this answer, I'm out of votes for today, otherwise it would have -1. It is completely incorrect. FYI, ctx is the context, the same as 'this' when in an Activity (that's what you are doing). holder is a ViewHolder object that Atif is using and because he's too lazy cleaning up the code he copy/pasted, he just left that in this trash code of an answer too, because why not. He's also suggesting to add another library on top of Picasso, which is not needed but will make your app apk heavier.

Comment: @Parmeetsinghanand now try this code Hope it may help you.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144261/discussion-between-atif-abbasi-and-2dee).

Comment: @Parmeetsinghanand I have given you running code its working perfectly fine for me .!